# md5 hash of file calculated not correct in Python

Tags: python, hash, md5, hashlib

I have a function for calculating the md5 hashes of all the files in a drive. A hash is calculated but it's different from the hash I got using other programs or online services that are designed for that.

```
def md5_files(path, blocksize = 2**20):
    hasher = hashlib.md5()
    hashes = {}
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            print(file_path)
            with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
                data = f.read(blocksize)
                if not data:
                    break
                hasher.update(data)
                hashes[file_path] = hasher.hexdigest()
    return hashes
```

the `path` provided is the drive letter, for example "K:\" then I navigate through the files and I open the file for binary read. I read chunks of data of the size specified in `blocksize`. Then I store the filename and md5 hash of every file in a dictionary called `hashes`. The code looks okay, I also checked other questions on Stack Overflow. I don't know why the generated md5 hash is wrong.

Comment: You need to create a new `hasher` for each file.

Comment: Can I reuse the same variable? For example can I put "hasher = hashlib.md5()" in the inner loop? I mean, inside the "with" statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to construct a new md5 object for each file and read it completely. eg. like so

```
def md5_files(path, blocksize = 2**20):    
    hashes = {}
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            print(file_path)
            with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
                data = f.read(blocksize)
                hasher = hashlib.md5(data)
                while data:
                    data = f.read(blocksize)   
                    hasher.update(data)             
                hashes[file_path] = hasher.hexdigest()
    return hashes
```

Comment: ok I get what you mean. Is there a duplicated "data = f.read(blocksize)" assignment that isn't necessary in your code? I see one inside the "with" statement and one inside the "while" loop.

Comment: `data` must not be empty for entering the while-loop and a simple way to get this is reading to it before. (the data is not just thrown away but used in `hashlib.md5(data)`)

Comment: Yes I think I understand. It's right to check data before entering the while loop and data is used as a parameter by hashlib.md5(). I'm thinking about the scope of the variable data. It's a local variable and it should be accessible anywhere inside the function md5_files(), so can I execute hasher.update(data) directly without executing data = f.read(blocksize) again before?

Comment: hmm, anyway if I remove "data = f.read(blocksize)" inside the "with statement" it seems there is like an infinite loop, instead if I do like you said, it processes the current file and then moves to the next. I'm not sure why, but it seems "data = f.read(blocksize)" inside the "with" statement is necessary.

Comment: I tested the function and it works. I'll accept your answer. Thanks for you help.